# Laravel migration seed using symbols

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Why doesn't laravel migrate store the euro sign when running a regular migrate from the command prompt?

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO `currencies` (`code`, `name`, `symbol`) VALUES  ('USD', 'US Dollar', '$'), ('EUR', 'Euro', '€');";
    DB::statement($query);
```

But when I manually update the field it stores just fine.

The settings in my database.php are:

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

Comment: it does not store second raw at all or euro sign is empty there?

Comment: Only the euro sign isn't stored. The rest goes well, just like the $ symbol

Comment: man.. do you have somthing like 'EUR', 'Euro' there? not about '€' now

Comment: I want to add the symbol too... In plain PHP this works great, so I am wondering why in Laravel it won't work

Comment: When you say you "manually update it" - does that mean via the MySQL command line client? PHPMyAdmin? Or some other way?

Comment: Manually via phpMyAdmin, by inserting or by running the exact query

Comment: what db engine are you using

Comment: can you try a different approach in inserting. like inserting it through your currency model?

Answer (score 1):

I'd check the encoding of your database connection.

In `config/database.php`, look for the `charset` and `collation` values - if they're not set to `utf8` (or some variation thereof - the collation will be a longer string containing "utf8"), then the euro character is probably getting dropped somewhere between your application and the database.

From what I understand, `charset` controls the set of characters available within your SQL statements (including any parameters). If you attempt to use a character from a different charset, it will be dropped.

The `collation` controls the way characters are sorted and compared by the MySQL engine. If you attempt to sort a column which contains characters not included in the collation for that column, then they will be sorted incorrectly.

For more details on `charset` and `collation`, [here is an explanation from the MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-general.html).

Comment: Kryten, I have adapted my question with the lines from my database.php settings. As you can see I have it set like you suggested

Comment: Well, then, I'm stumped :-p